# Dynamic LINQ or multiple columns

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I'm using [DynamicLinq](https://dynamic-linq.net/) on my Net Core Web API. The main purpose is to select data based on multiple columns filtered by `OR`

This is the Model

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

The query looks like this. (I create generic method to handle all of the tables)

```
public static async Task<List<T>> Query<T>(this DbContext context, Dictionary<string, string> filter) where T : class
{
    var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    string whereClause = "";
    foreach(var d in filter)
    {
        if (whereClause != "")
            whereClause += " || ";

        whereClause += $"{d.Key}.Contains(\"{d.Value}\")";
    }

    return await query.Where(whereClause).ToListAsync();
}
```

This code generates no errors but the `where clause` is skipped which means it's executed like there's no `Where` and resulted all the data. The result query looks like `SELECT Id, Name, Brand FROM Car` where it should be like `SELECT Id, Name, Brand FROM Car WHERE Name LIKE '%something%' OR Brand LIKE '%something%'`

**[EDIT]**

Trying this [online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvX4Ou) works well when running `customers.AsQueryable().Where("Name.Contains(\"David\") || Name.Contains(\"Gail\")")`

Comment: I have to ask the obvious, does the dictionary contain any items?

Comment: Yes, of course it has items

Comment: I don't know dynamic-linq, but I skimmed thrugh the documentation and it doesn't seem to mention Contains as an operator. It's not a SQL operator either, how would you have dynamic-linq translate it?

Comment: You might also [consider using PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your generic method in both Dotnet 5 & Dotnet 6. everything was work correctly. I think your problem solve if you use the latest version of Dotnet & EfCore & Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: This should be a **Comment** not an **Answer**